# Select query returning no records/results if another filed is blank/null

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form with various fields used to filter a select query built on a single table. Problem is that some of the fields in the record (which are also potential criteria fields) are null/blank e.g."FirstName" & "LastName" may both be blank but there IS a "StudentID".

When entering a "StudentID" associated with a record that has all other fields null/blank the query does not return the record but rather returns no records at all. **I would like the query to return all records that are associated with the particular criteria despite other fields being blank/null.**

In the past, I have assigned a default value like "NoName..." on all new records so the field is not blank and that works but annoying...

**I am having a brain fart... Please let me know if more info is needed. TYIA**

```
SELECT 
    SAP_RECORD_T.FirstName, 
    SAP_RECORD_T.LastName, 
    SAP_RECORD_T.StudentID,
    SAP_RECORD_T.Term, 
    SAP_RECORD_T.FileComplete, 
    SAP_RECORD_T.CampusSubmitted
FROM SAP_RECORD_T
WHERE 
    (
        ((SAP_RECORD_T.FirstName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtFName] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.LastName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtLName] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.StudentID) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![StudentID] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.Term) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtTerm] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.FileComplete) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtFileCmplt] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.CampusSubmitted) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtCampus] & "*")
    ) OR (
        ((SAP_RECORD_T.FirstName) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.LastName) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.StudentID) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.Term) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.FileComplete) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.CampusSubmitted) Is Null)
    );
```

Comment: Why not build the WHERE clause dynamically based on which fields have values entered?  If a textbox is empty then don't include that as a criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the logic in the conditions of the  `WHERE` clause.

Your `WHERE` clause :

```
WHERE 
    (
        ((SAP_RECORD_T.FirstName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtFName] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.LastName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtLName] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.StudentID) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![StudentID] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.Term) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtTerm] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.FileComplete) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtFileCmplt] & "*") 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.CampusSubmitted) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtCampus] & "*")
    ) OR (
        ((SAP_RECORD_T.FirstName) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.LastName) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.StudentID) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.Term) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.FileComplete) Is Null) 
        AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.CampusSubmitted) Is Null)
    )
```

As it is, your conditions allow records that either match on all search box conditions, or where all filter columns are `NULL`. Instead, you want to check `NULL`ity for each column individually before applying the filter.

New version :

```
WHERE 
    (
        ( 
            ((SAP_RECORD_T.FirstName) Is Null)  
            OR ((SAP_RECORD_T.FirstName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtFName] & "*") 
        )
        AND (
            ((SAP_RECORD_T.LastName) Is Null) 
            OR ((SAP_RECORD_T.LastName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtLName] & "*")  
        )
        AND (
            ((SAP_RECORD_T.StudentID) Is Null)
            OR ((SAP_RECORD_T.StudentID) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![StudentID] & "*")
        ) 
        AND (
            ((SAP_RECORD_T.Term) Is Null) 
            OR ((SAP_RECORD_T.Term) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtTerm] & "*") 
        )
        AND (
            ((SAP_RECORD_T.FileComplete) Is Null) 
            OR ((SAP_RECORD_T.FileComplete) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtFileCmplt] & "*") 
        )
        AND (
            ((SAP_RECORD_T.CampusSubmitted) Is Null)
            OR ((SAP_RECORD_T.CampusSubmitted) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtCampus] & "*")
        )
    )
```

NB : these things are easier to spot when the query is properly formated (indentation, ...).

Comment: Thank you! Works Great! I am still very new and teaching myself SQL and Access. I appreciate your constructive criticism. I will read up on proper formatting. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome @StanS, glad that it helped !

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ((SAP_RECORD_T.FirstName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtFName] & "*") 
OR ((SAP_RECORD_T.FirstName) Is Null)
AND ((SAP_RECORD_T.LastName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchBox_F]![txtLName] & "*") 
OR((SAP_RECORD_T.LastName) Is Null)
```

Similarly, for other columns, check if the column matches criteria OR is null.